# What is the causing my solution to precipitate?

Tags: solubility

I have a solution that contains M9 Minimal Media 5X, Glucose, Magnesium Sulfate, Calcium Chloride and L-Phenylalanine. When the solution is pH'd to 8.5 with 4M Sodium Hydroxide, it starts to precipitate. What is the causing the solution to precipitate?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably precipitating Calcium Hydroxide and Magnesium Hydroxide since you are adding a very concentrated NaOH solution to it. Not sure if this is what you've asked though.